# What is the value of $|\sin(\cos\theta + i \sin\theta)| $ in complex analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, absolute-value

How would I compute the value to/simplify the following expression?

> $$\left|\sin\left( \cos\theta + i \sin\theta \vphantom{M^M} \right) \right| $$

Can I use the fact that $\cos\theta + i \sin\theta = e^{i\theta}$ and work from there?

Comment: By definition, $\sin(z)=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$ for any $z\in\mathbb{C}$. You may want to use this for $z=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta=e^{i\theta}$

Comment: @JulianMejia Ok, so then this would simplify to |sin(z)|, correct?  Out of curiosity, is this the same as max |sin(z)| about the unit circle?

Comment: To get $|\sin z|$ you need to use $|\sin(z)|^2=\sin(z)\overline{\sin(z)}$, and you may want to use the fact that $\overline{\sin(z)}=\sin(\overline{z})$. Now, your other question, I didn't understand it what do you mean by max? You are trying to compute $|\sin(z)| $ not a max.

Comment: @JulianMejia I was asking if the above express would, after simplification, result in |sinz| and if the value of this function is the same as the max |sinz| about the unit circle.

Comment: No, these are two different things. $|\sin z|$ is just the value at some particular point of the unit circle, namely at $z=e^{i\theta}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value of $|\sin(\cos\theta + i \sin\theta)|$ is indeed the image of mapping $f(z)=|\sin z|$ under unit circle $|z|=1$, which is a real number. One may write
$$\sin(\cos\theta + i \sin\theta) $$
$$= \sin(\cos\theta)\cos(i\sin\theta) + \cos(\cos\theta)\sin(i\sin\theta)$$
$$ = \sin(\cos\theta)\cosh(\sin\theta) + i\cos(\cos\theta)\sinh(\sin\theta)$$